# directional derivative of following function

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification

can someone verify this

> let $f(x,y) = \frac{x^2 y }{x^4 + y^2}$  forall $(x,y) \neq (0,0)$ and $f(0,0)  = (0,0)$ find $\textbf{v}$ for which does directional derivative exists at $\textbf{0}$

$D_{\textbf{v}} f(\textbf{0}) = \lim_{t \rightarrow 0} \frac{f(tv_1, tv_2) - f(0,0)}{t}$

$\hspace{1.4cm} = \lim_{t \rightarrow 0} \frac{v_1^2v_2}{t^2 v_1^4 + v_2^2}$

$D_{\textbf{v}}(\textbf{0}) = \begin{cases} 
      (v_1/v_2)^2 & v_2 \neq 0 \\
      \infty & v_2 = 0 
   \end{cases}$

Comment: Isn’t the expression you ended up with identically zero when $v_2=0$?

Comment: @amd my bad. you are correct! can your write an answer so that I can accept

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your solution is not correct.

If $v_2=0$, then $\frac{v_1^2v_2}{t^2 v_1^4 + v_2^2}=0 \to 0$ as $t \to 0.$

$v_2 \ne 0$, then $\frac{v_1^2v_2}{t^2 v_1^4 + v_2^2} \to \frac{v_1^2v_2}{v_2^2}=\frac{v_1^2}{v_2}$ as $t \to 0.$